# The long time approximation from the asymptotic power series

Tags: asymptotics

**what is the long time approximation from the  following the asymptotic series function?**
$$t^{3\alpha-2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{m=0}^\infty\frac{(-it^{\alpha})^{n}}{Γ(n\alpha+2\alpha)}\frac{(it^{\alpha})^{m}}{Γ(m\alpha+\alpha)}$$
**Thanks for your advice.**

Comment: Your series is a product of Mittag-Leffler functions whose asymptotics can be found in [this paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00365-001-0019-3).

Comment: [This $\texttt{arXiv paper can be useful}$](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0909.0230.pdf).

Comment: that's mean: long time approximation for Mittag-Leffler function is $$E_{\alpha,2\alpha}(-it^{\alpha})\sim-\frac{(-it^{\alpha})^{-1}}{Γ(2\alpha-\alpha)}$$ and$$ E_{\alpha,\alpha}(it^{\alpha})\sim-\frac{(it^{\alpha})^{-1}}{Γ(\alpha-\alpha)}$$

Comment: but $$E_{\alpha,\alpha}(-it^{\alpha})\sim-\frac{(it^{\alpha})^{-1}}{Γ(\alpha-\alpha)}$$ in denominator will be infinity and total phrase will be zero. can you help me in to solve this problem? thanks for your advice.